# Enable -race on compiled binary

Tags: go

I'm trying to enable the race detector: https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector

Since I can't upload the source code to the test server, how can I enable `-race` or compile a binary with `-race` enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `-race` to however you're building now, as stated in the document you've linked to in your question.

For example,

```
go build -race main.go
```